# Django how to prevent to accept future date?

Tags: python, django

I added this validation in my froms.py for prevent to accept future date. But I am not undersating why it's not working and forms still now submitting with future date. here is my code:

```
import datetime
 
class AddPatientFrom(forms.ModelForm):
         
         date_of_birth =  forms.DateField(widget=forms.DateInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control','type':'date'}),required=True)
       
         class Meta:
             model = Patient
             fields = ['date_of_birth']
         
         def clean_date(self):
                date = self.cleaned_data['date_of_birth']
                if date < datetime.date.today():
                    raise forms.ValidationError("The date cannot be in the past!")
                return date
```

I also want to know how to disable to pick future date from Django default html calendar?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are checking the opposite: it will rase an error if the date of birth is *before* today. You should check if the date of birth is *after* today when raising a validation error, so:

```
def clean_date_of_birth(self):
    date = self.cleaned_data['date_of_birth']
    if date > datetime.date.today():  # 🖘 raise error if greater than
        raise forms.ValidationError("The date cannot be in the future!")
    return date
```

Comment: I also tried gather then but didn't work

Comment: @boyenec: ah, but since your field is `date_of_birth`, it should be `clean_date_of_birth`.

Comment: still now forms submitting after using `>`

Comment: @boyenec: yes, but another problem is that since you did not name it `clean_date_of_birth`, it will not be triggered.

Comment: Willem Van Onsem thanks. can you please little bit explain why it's now working for `clean_date_of_birth`?

Comment: @boyenec: If you have a field named `foo`, then Django will look if there is a `clean_foo` method, and call this to validate the `foo` field. If there is a `clean_other` field, but there is no `other` form field, then Django will not call this for validation.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240656/discussion-between-boyenec-and-willem-van-onsem).

Comment: isn't the error message is `"The date cannot be in the future"`

Comment: @suhailvs: yes, I copied it from the question. Fixed, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your validation logic only raises error for past dates, not future dates.

Moreover, to validate `date_of_birth` field you need to implement `clean_date_of_birth` method.

From [Form and field validation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/#form-and-field-validation) docs.

> The `clean_<fieldname>()` method is called on a form subclass – where `<fieldname>` is replaced with the name of the form field attribute. This method does any cleaning that is specific to that particular attribute, unrelated to the type of field that it is...